# C++ Merge Sort Output Issue

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to write a Merge Sort Algorithm, but for some unknown reason to me, it corrupts the numbers in the sorting process (When I say corrupted, I mean that it's outputting large negative numbers where the actual numbers in the array should be). Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// A Merge Sort templace function
template <class T>
void mergeSort(T list[], int LB, int UB)
{
    int mid;
    if (LB < UB)
    {
        mid = (LB + UB) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, LB, mid);
        mergeSort(list, mid + 1, UB);
        merge(list, LB, mid, UB);
    }
}

template <class T>
void merge(T list[], int LB, int mid, int UB)
{
    int size1 = mid - LB + 1;
    int size2 = UB - mid;
    int i, j, k;
    T *temp1 = new T[size1];
    T *temp2 = new T[size2];

    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        temp1[i] = list[LB + i - 1];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < size2; j++)
    {
        temp2[j] = list[mid + j];
    }

    i = 1;
    j = i;

    for (k = LB; k <= UB; k++)
    {
        if (temp1[i] <= temp2[j])
        {
            list[k] = temp1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            list[k] = temp2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    delete[] temp1;
    delete[] temp2;
}

int main()
{
    const int X = 10;
    int list[X] = { 10, 70, 80, 40, 20, 50, 30, 60, 100, 90 };
    int LB = 0;
    int UB = X - 1;

    mergeSort(list, LB, UB);

    for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    {
       cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I know I must be missing something trivial, and to be honest, I don't really know what I'm doing, but any help I can get will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Suggestion, whenever you suspect the solution to your problem is trivial, [break out the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger). It was literally built for this. Run your program under the debugger and step through the code line by line until you see `list` back in the `main` function get smashed. It happens pretty fast in your case. This will tell you where bad happens and from there, run the program again to see how the bad value that was written into `list` was computed. Maybe you have do this a few more times walking your way back to the source of the error.

Comment: When you suspect your problem isn't trivial, use the debugger to narrow it down. Then isolate the problem and attack it the same way you would a trivial problem. There is no such thing as a big problem. So-called big problems are just bunches of little problems working together. Divide and conquer.

Comment: You have several off-by-1 errors in your subscripting.